# Which is best way to represent huge data using Web.API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

> **Case1:**

```
 var query = (from p in db.TblPost where (from q in db.TblThread 
        where q.LocationLocationid == locationID && q.CategoriesCategoryid == categoryID select q.Threadid).Contains(p.ThreadThreadid) 
        join r in db.TblThread on p.ThreadThreadid equals r.Threadid join s in db.TblUser on p.UserUserid equals s.Userid join t 
        in db.TblCategories on r.CategoriesCategoryid equals t.Categoryid join u in db.TblLocation on r.LocationLocationid 
        equals u.Locationid orderby r.CreatedTime descending 
        select new { p, r.Subject, r.EventAddress, r.EventClosetime, r.EventDate, r.EventDuration, r.EventStarttime, 
        r.EventTitle, r.IseventAllday, r.TargetUsers, r.CreatedTime, s.FirstName, s.MiddleName, s.LastName, t.Name, 
        u.Locationname, r.Isreadonly }).ToList();
```

**OR**

> **Case 2:**

```
                List<TblPost> _tblPost = new List<TblPost>();
                _tblPost = (from p in db.TblPost select p).ToList();

                List<TblThread> _tblThread = new List<TblThread>();
                _tblThread = (from p in db.TblThread select p).ToList();

                List<TblUser> _tblUser = new List<TblUser>();
                _tblUser = (from p in db.TblUser select p).ToList();

                List<TblLocation> _tblLocation = new List<TblLocation>();
                _tblLocation = (from p in db.TblLocation select p).ToList();

                List<TblCategories> _tblCategory = new List<TblCategories>();
                _tblCategory = (from p in db.TblCategories select p).ToList();


 var query = (from p in _tblPost where (from q in _tblThread where q.LocationLocationid == locationID 
         && q.CategoriesCategoryid == categoryID select q.Threadid).Contains(p.ThreadThreadid) join r in _tblThread on p.ThreadThreadid 
         equals r.Threadid join s in _tblUser on p.UserUserid equals s.Userid join t in _tblCategory on r.CategoriesCategoryid equals 
         t.Categoryid join u in _tblLocation on r.LocationLocationid equals u.Locationid orderby r.CreatedTime descending 
         select new { p, r.Subject, r.EventAddress, r.EventClosetime, r.EventDate, r.EventDuration, r.EventStarttime, 
         r.EventTitle, r.IseventAllday, r.TargetUsers, r.CreatedTime, s.FirstName, s.MiddleName, s.LastName, 
         t.Name, u.Locationname, r.Isreadonly }).ToList();
```

I've these two codes which results the same. But, in `case 2` i'm getting the result some quickly as compared to `case 1`. Which one should i need to follow?

Shall i follow `case 2`? is it right way to get huge data in `Web.API`?

Comment: Huge data always requires paging, user will not see hundreds of rows at one time, and `case 2` is very wrong method it will have multiple query execution.

Comment: But, i'm getting result quickly. For paging can you share any code or link to follow?